# Vue @click.stop still getting the child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to get the child elements of the parent component.

```
<div
    v-on:click.stop.prevent="onClickTemplateHandler">
    <div>
    <h3 style="">Title</h3>
    <p>{{ lorem }}</p>
    </div>
</div>


...


onClickTemplateHandler(e) {
    console.log(e)
    const innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML
    if (innerHTML) {
      this.value += innerHTML
    }
}
```

I've tried to use `.self`, but I still want the inner of the div be clickable

But, when I click the inside of the div, I am getting the child as the target instead of the parent.

Any suggestion for this one?

Thanks!

Comment: What does it log on console? And what did you expect instead? After you [edit] these outputs, we can help better.

Comment: Hi. thanks for your comment. I figured it out by putting an overlay. I posted my answer.

Comment: https://javascript.info/event-delegation

Answer (score 0):

I did some workaround

```
<div>
    <div class="overlay" v-on:click.stop.prevent="onClickTemplateHandler"></div>
    <div>
      <h3 style="padding: 10px;text-align: center;">Header</h3>
    </div>
</div>


...

onClickTemplateHandler(e) {
    const innerHTML = e.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML
    if (innerHTML) {
      this.value += innerHTML
    }
}

...

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```